# What can make the output of a simple ada program indent, when not told to?

Tags: format, output, ada

I am currently doing the Ada tutorial from [learn.adacore.com](https://learn.adacore.com/index.html), and I am now at the second example: reading and outputting an integer. Since copy-pasting is for people who don't want to learn the syntax, I manually typed out most of the code (Some of it was generated by gnat-gps, but I'm now using vim).

I compiled and ran the program, and surprisingly, the second line of output is indented by roughly one tab. Why?

Here's the code:

```ada
With Ada.Text_IO;
Use Ada.Text_IO;
With Ada.Integer_Text_IO;
use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;

procedure Main is
    N : Integer;
begin
   --  Insert code here.
    Put("Enter an integer value: ");
    Get(N);
    if N>0 then
        Put (N);
        Put_Line(" is a positive number");
    end if;
end Main;
```

(how do I get syntax highlighting?)

Here is a sample of the output (the first 1 being input):

```
Enter an integer value: 1
          1 is a positive number
```

Comment: I edited to add syntax highlightling. I think that on Github I’d have said `\`\`\`ada` instead of `\`\`\` lang-ada`.

Comment: The syntax highlighting doesn't seem to work very well. I've taken a look, and it is due to the syntax highlighter lacking support for Ada. It is [code-prettify](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work). There was already a [patch](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/issues/312) for providing support for Ada, so I've updated it and made a [pull request](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/pull/601).Now it only needs that Google process the 44 pending pull requests...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Put procedure from Ada.Integer_Text_IO uses a default field width padded with spaces.
The specification for that procedure is defined in the [Ada Language Reference Manual](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-TOC.html) as:

```
procedure Put(Item  : in Num;
              Width : in Field := Default_Width;
              Base  : in Number_Base := Default_Base);
```

The Width and Base parameters are given default values. Your call to Put only supplied a value for the formal parameter Item. To eliminate the left padding simply specify a desired width. I suggest you use Ada named notation for the call as in

```
Put(Item => N, Width => 1);
```

Comment: That’s at [ARM A.10.8(11)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-A-10-8.html#p11). You could set `Width` to 0.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it does explain what I was asking. However, I don't really understand what width and base actually *do*. Could you please explain/summarize so that future readers do not have to look at external reference material?

Comment: The Width field specifies the minimum number of characters used to output the integer value. This field is right-justified. Careful use of the Width field allows easy output of right-justified columnar data. The Base field allows you to choose the number base for the output. Ada supports bases in the range of 2 through 16. The default output base is 10. The output for bases other than 10 uses the format "base#value#. For example, if you choose to print the number 13 (base 10) in base 2 the output will be 2#1101#, while base 16 will produce 16#D#.